# Different key generation algorithms used in different blockchains

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum, corda

I was researching on various key generation algorithms used in different kinds of blockchains out there in market.
I wanted to know which algorithms are used to generate public/private key pairs in following blockchains:

1. Ethereum
2. Hyperledger-Fabric
3. R3 Corda

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you find Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the signature schemes supported by Ethereum or Hyperledger Fabric.

Corda is cryptographically agile, with multiple signature schemes available based on the desired trade-offs between cryptographic strength, compatibility with various HSM vendors, algorithm standardisation, variety of cryptographic primitives, business demand, option for post-quantum resistance, side channel security, efficiency and degree of testing.

As of version 3, Corda supports five signature schemes:

**1. Pure EdDSA using the ed25519 curve and SHA-512**

EdDSA is the current state of the art in mainstream cryptography. It implements elliptic curve cryptography with deterministic signatures, a fast implementation, explained constants, side channel resistance and many other
desirable characteristics. However, it is relatively new and not widely supported. For example, you can’t use it in TLS yet (a draft RFC exists but is not standardised yet).

This is the default signature scheme for the node's well-known and confidential identities, and for the network bootstrapper.

**2. ECDSA using the NIST P-256 curve (secp256r1) and SHA-256**

This is the default choice for most systems that support elliptic curve cryptography today and is recommended by NIST. It is also supported by the majority of the HSM vendors.

This is the default signature scheme for the root network certificate authority, the doorman, the node certificate authority (which issues the node's identity and TLS keys), the node's TLS keys, and the network map on the Corda Network.

**3. ECDSA using the Koblitz k1 curve (secp256k1) and SHA-256**

secp256k1 is the curve adopted by Bitcoin and as such there is a wealth of infrastructure, code and advanced algorithms designed for use with it. This curve is standardised by NIST as part of the “Suite B” cryptographic algorithms and as such is more widely supported than ed25519. By supporting it, Corda gains access to the ecosystem of advanced cryptographic techniques and devices pioneered by the Bitcoin community.

**4. RSA (3072bit) PKCS#1 and SHA-256**

RSA is well supported by any sort of hardware or software as a signature algorithm no matter how old. For example, legacy HSMs will support this, as will obsolete operating systems. RSA is using bigger keys than ECDSA and thus it is recommended for inclusion only for its backwards compatibility properties, and only for usage where legacy constraints or government regulation forbids the usage of more modern approaches.

**5. SPHINCS-256 and SHA-512 (experimental)**

SPHINCS-256 is a post-quantum secure algorithm that relies only on hash functions. It is included as a hedge against the possibility of a malicious adversary obtaining a quantum computer capable of running Shor’s algorithm in future. SPHINCS is based ultimately on a clever usage of Merkle hash trees. Hash functions are a very heavily studied and well understood area of cryptography. Thus, it is assumed that there is a much lower chance of breakthrough attacks on the underlying mathematical problems. However, compared to the EdDSA, ECDSA and RSA algorithms, SPHINCS uses relatively big public keys, it is slower, and it outputs bigger signatures.